# How do I get Ubuntu Budgie using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, upgrade

I would like to upgrade my Ubuntu installation to Budgie from the OS presently on my computer (Ubuntu 17.04). How do I get the upgrade using the command line? I tried `sudo apt-get ubuntu`, but received an error message stating that "ubuntu" is an unrecognized (invalid) command. What is the correct syntax for upgrade requests using the terminal?

Comment: The error is correct; the usual commands are `sudo apt-get update`  (to update your software [repo] lists), followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` (or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to allow more updates).   You'll however likely run into issues as 17.04 is now well-past EOL, and the repos that were in `archive.ubuntu.com` are no in `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, plus the 17.04 upgrade path was to 17.10 (which itself is EOL now too; though only days ago and its archives haven't moved yet).  I'd suggest downloading a 18.04 Ubuntu-Budgie ISO & install that...

Comment: I'd (1) backup your data, (2) download & write Ubuntu-Budgie ISO to thumb-drive or dvdr(w), then (3) boot & test it with 'try ubuntu' (ensure it works fine on your hardware, then do an install.  I'd suggest using the 'something else' & then point out your partitions, ensuring the 'format' box for each is NOT selected (so files are preserved) then install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release  (How to install software or upgrade from an old supported release)   ... this contains clues on changing `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` I mentioned in first comment; also you need to remove any country codes (eg. `us.archive.ubuntu.com` becomes `old-releases.ubuntu.com` as country mirrors only apply for current releases).  To update from terminal you'll have to go this route, but a re-install is easier...

Comment: Typically you should be able to just run `sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop` and that's it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](/q/91815/175814) combined with [How to install Ubuntu Budgie over Ubuntu](/q/1032211/175814)